# Elasticsearch - How to get last Id?

Tags: elasticsearch

I need the last id of a type called 'Mail', and the Id is Bigint, but for some reason I get the 5 first rows...
What to do?

This is my query:

```
{
  "fields": [
    "SentMail_Upload_Session_BigIntID"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "SentMail_Upload_Session_BigIntID": "desc"
  },
  "size": 1
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The query should work depending on your mapping. Can you clarify what you mean by first 5 rows?

ElasticSearch will generally take your fields and convert them to camelCase, are you sure the field is SentMail_Upload_Session_BigIntID and not sentMail_Upload_Session_BigIntID?

Also while this is possible with ES, would it be possible to use a call to your database? ElasticSearch is a text based search server, and this type of call fits snuggly into the type of call you would want to access your db for.

Comment: The field name is excely 'SentMail_Upload_Session_BigIntID'.
Maybe my problem is that in the Elasticsearch head plugin the query starts with 'default_1/Mail/_search' and i should specific the type in filter?